# how to display buttons in tab bar programmaticaly in iphone

Tags: iphone

Im new to iphone development. here in my application i want to add two buttons in tab bar.

here i displayed barbutton item in view but i dont no how to display buttons in tab bar.

can any one plz help me about my problem. how to display buttons in tab bar programmaticaly in iphone.

thank you in advance.

Comment: learn first,how to place question,I did n't get what do u want in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the UITabBar-documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can use

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to set items to your tabbar. 
This array of items needs to contain UITabBarItems, check out the UITabBarItems-documentation for this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

A complete exaple would be:

```
UITabBarItem *barItem1 = [UITabBarItem alloc]
                         initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemRecents 
                                              tag:10];
[mytabbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:barItem1, nil] animated:NO];
[barItem1 release];
```

I just wrote this out of my head now, so check the code in xcode, it may fail.

Good luck :-)